# Unzip/Extracting file on server-side- Worklight

Tags: post, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ibm-mobilefirst

Is there a way to download a zip file with a POST to a server and unzip it? I am using HTTP Adapter. Also, i do not understand how to perform a POST request to the server in worklight.

I have tried to use a java based adapter to add http post request to the server, but i dont knw how we can access the file system to save the file. is it possible to do this in a java based adapter on worklight ?

Comment: What is your use case that you need to download a zip file to the **worklight server**?

Comment: You are not explaining your use case... WHY do you need to retrieve a ZIP file and store it on the WORKLIGHT SERVER?

Comment: Here is the usecase.. 
i have a test case on the server, which i want to execute on my mobile. To do that, there is a REST service, which on POST request,  will give me a zip file containing details of the test case. i need to get that test case downloaded, extracted and run on my mobile device.

Comment: sorry i havent seen your comment about Usecase..

Comment: I ask again, what does this have to do with the Worklight Server? Have the zip file stored somewhere, and in the client (the app), pull the zip file using Cordova API. You cannot use an adapter to store files on the worklight server. What is in this zip file? What are you trying to run on the device?

Comment: there is a test case record on jazz.net server. i have to download that test case record, and the service gives me a response in the form of .zip file. the file contains data to run the test case.(an xml file with test case info, manifest file, images related to test case etc). So now where can i download this file from jazz.net and store it?

Comment: i have to render the xml i got in the .zip file and modify it when the test case is run on the mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

- See page #15 in [Module 4_2 HTTP adapter](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/04_02_HTTP_adapter_-_Communicating_with_HTTP_back-end_systems.pdf) for how to use POST in Worklight adapters.
- You can use [Cordova FileTransfer API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) to download a file to the **device filesystem**.

To the best of my knowledge you cannot download data into the **Worklight Server** and make use of it afterwards.

Comment: so how can i download a file from a web server and extract it to the application ?

Comment: Read my answer. Use the Cordova FileTransfer API to retrieve and save the file to the device filesystem. Find code to unzip.

Comment: But can we do a POST call with parameters using Cordova FileTransfer API? I have a POST call to do, where i will get a .zip file as a response.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly then your question has nothing to do with Worklight.
You can do it with http adapter calling a web service that you need to create that will handle it (for example the web service will do a cURL to the zip file via post, will unzip it and send the XML back to the Worklight server and from there to the client).
You can do it with a Java adapter that will do the same thing, but I strongly recommend against it. The Worklight server should not be used for things like that.

Comment: hi, i am not clear with this. can you pls explain a bit? Please excuse my ignorance.